# Could not load NIB in bundle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xib

I am getting this error...

```
enter code here
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:     'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/patrontechnosoft/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/EBCB993E-A707-4121-BE4C-13B34466B44D/New GMAT - Practice.app> (loaded)' with name 'IRAnswerViewController_iPad''
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a88052 0x1c99d0a 0x1a30a78 0x1a309e9 0x584838 0x42be2c 0x42c3a9 0x42c5cb 0x447b89 0x4479bd 0x445f8a 0x445e2f 0x4478f4 0x1a89ec9 0x3695c2 0x36955a 0x58e569 0x1a89ec9 0x3695c2 0x36955a 0x40eb76 0x40f03f 0x40ebab 0x590d1f 0x1a89ec9 0x3695c2 0x36955a 0x40eb76 0x40f03f 0x40e2fe 0x38ea30 0x38ec56 0x375384 0x368aa9 0x23d1fa9 0x1a5c1c5 0x19c1022 0x19bf90a 0x19bedb4 0x19beccb 0x23d0879 0x23d093e 0x366a9b 0x1d5a 0x1ca5)
terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Provide some details. It's difficult do understand what is going on.

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE: to understand....

Comment: especially first two of the following links could hold the answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401105/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-ind-bundle, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415252/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099707/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle

Comment: We need to see some code

Comment: What part of `Could not load NIB in bundle:... with name 'IRAnswerViewController_iPad` was unclear? It seems pretty straightforward as to what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you use correct spelling in `initWithNibName:`.

Many people do make spelling mistakes here and get an error. Make a habit of copy and pasting, so there's less chance for error.

Comment: Please use proper English instead of textspeak when writing questions and answers. "Plz", "u", and "hv" are not real words, and they are painful to read here.